# Heatmap with two different colour keys with heatmap.2() function

Tags: r, heatmap, p-value, gplots, color-key

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxD3t.png)

I am trying to figure out how to get an Heatmap with two different colour keys: one for my values (which belong to the first and second columns of my matrix "df1") and a different one for my pvalue (determined by the difference between my first and second column). I have 50 different observations in total (50 rows and 3 columns). 
Does anyone get an idea on how to plot the pvalue column with a different colour map?

This is how my code looks like:

```
df1<-as.matrix(df)
yb<-colorRampPalette(c("lightcyan","darkblue", "red"))
heatmap.2(df1,
      trace=NULL,         
      margins = c(2,20),
      colsep = c(1,2,3),
      col=yb,
      tracecol = NULL,
      key.title = NA,
      cexCol = 1,
      srtCol = 0,
      adjCol = 1,
      sepcolor="black",
      sepwidth=c(0.0001,0.001),
      rowsep=1:nrow(df1),
      Colv = FALSE,
      keysize = 1,
      key.xlab = "Normalized plaques count",
      key.ylab = NA)
```

Comment: Do you have any reproducible data on hand?

Comment: I added a link showing how my data frame looks like. If you can help me, I appreciate it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the intended use of `heatmap2` - it seems you really need two different plots. The values in one plot and the p-values in another. You would need to customise code I think to plot those together (which would not strictly be correct anyway) and I suspect this would be more trouble than it is worth. Some stuff is easier in a graphics editor unless you are intending to produce very many of these.